# Validate complex type using terraform

Tags: validation, terraform

Im trying to validate a terraform complex map. The map contains a list of objects with multiple attributes. I was trying to validate each attribute and unfortunately, it seems that whatever condition I put, it is ok. It's like the validation is always true.

Could anyone have a look and see what I'm doing wrong? Also, would it be possible to validate map keys?

```
variable "complexmap" {
  type = map(object(
    {
      reference = string 
      type = string
      count = string
    }
  ))

  default = {
    "key1" = {
      count = "5"
      reference = "refcode1"
      type = "novel"
    }, 
    "key2" = {
      count = "2"
      reference = "REFcode2"
      type = "comics"
    }, 
  }

  validation {
         condition = (
             alltrue([for v in var.complexmap : (
                 can(regex("[a-z0-9]{4,10}", v["reference"])) 
                 && v["count"] >= 2 && v["count"] < 10
                 && (v["type"] == "novel" || v["type"] == "comics")
             )])
         )
         error_message = "Validation of an object failed."
     }
}
```

Comment: The variable `default` value will validate with your `validation` block. If you want it to fail, then you need to supply a value that would fail the validation, or create a failing condition for the validation. I have reproduced locally that the values validate, and fail validation if modified to fail (e.g. `count = 1`).

Comment: In this case, validation should fail because in second object (key2), I have upper letters. But still validation is ok...

Comment: Your regular expression checks that there is between four and ten characters among `a-z` and `0-9`. Therefore, those values will validate.

Comment: But only lower cases characters. No? a-z is not the same as A-Za-z. Is it?

Comment: So other than `number` types cast as `string` types in your default value, this is more of a regular expression question. You may want to ask a new question around that.

Comment: I Validate complex type using terraform.
Could you share valid code validation complexmap ? Thanks!